# Is anyone having problems with bundle install after installing el capitan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-elcapitan

When I type `bundle install`, it gives me this error:

> -bash: bundle: command not found

So I tried `gem install bundler -v 1.9.7`, and got this error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using sudo:

```
sudo gem install bundler -v 1.9.7
```

Make sure you're using a new version of ruby, instead of the one that comeswith Mac OS X. You can install a new one with [RVM](//:rvm.io):

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Comment: Attempted that, then this happened

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/cache/autoprefixer-rails-6.1.0.1.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing autoprefixer-rails (6.1.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '6.1.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: What happens when you do `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '6.1.0.1'`?

Comment: This: 

Fetching: autoprefixer-rails-6.1.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: Does `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` work?

Comment: Appeared to, got two warnings but I think they're normal.

Comment: @NiallHiggins ok try installing bundler again.

Comment: the bundler seems to install, the problem occurs when I run "bundle install"

Comment: yes It has, I followed your instructions and it unfortunately doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `sudo bundle install`?

Comment: Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.